# Display a <li> in reverse order in React project using inline CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, reverse

I have a react project that uses messaging, so I want the most recently added message to be displayed on the bottom. I've tried the 'reversed' property for HTML5 tags, but it doesn't seem to change anything in my browser (latest version of Chrome). I want to simply display my list in backwards order, how would I add it do my code? I have my render function below:

```
   render() {  

  var styles = {
    color: "#3895C4",
    fontSize: 25,
    fontFamily: "Courier New",
    background: "#eee",
    padding: "20px",
    margin: "20px",
    listStyleType: "none",
    transition: "opacity .25s ease-in";

  }
    return (
      <div >
      <form onSubmit={this.addMessage.bind(this)}>
        <input type="text" placeholder='Message' ref={ msg => this.input = msg }/>
        <input type="submit"/>
        <li style={styles}>
          { /* Render the list of messages */
            this.state.messages.map( message => <li reversed key={message.id}>{message.text}</li> )
          }
        </li>
        </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1 - Reverse the array**

You can [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array:

```
<ul style={styles}> // this should be a ul, and not li
  { /* Render the list of messages */
    this.state.messages.reverse().map(message => 
        <li reversed key={message.id}>{message.text}</li> 
    )
  }
</ul>
```

**Option 2 - Reverse the rendered items**

Instead of reversing the array, you can reverse the rendered items, by using a flexbox with `flexDirection: 'column-reverse'`:

```
var styles = {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column-reverse',
  color: "#3895C4",
  fontSize: 25,
  fontFamily: "Courier New",
  background: "#eee",
  padding: "20px",
  margin: "20px",
  listStyleType: "none",
  transition: "opacity .25s ease-in";
}

<ul style={styles}> // this should be a ul, and not li
  { /* Render the list of messages */
    this.state.messages.map((message) => 
        <li key={message.id}>{message.text}</li> 
    )
  }
</ul>
```